# Customize the Secondary filter in Kendo Grid

Tags: jquery, html, razor, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am able to Customise the primary Filters on Kendo Grid as:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Invoice.Models.ViewModels.DossierViewModel>()
.Name("Dossier")
.Columns(columns =>
{

    columns.Bound(p => p.CustomerName).Title("Customer").Width(150);

})
        .Filterable()
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Read(read => read.Action("Dossier_Read", "Dossier"))
        .Filter(x=>x.Add(y=>y.CustomerName).Contains(""))
       )
)
```

Here I am able to use "Contains" as Default primary filter as shown in Image below:
[image]

But I want also want to use `"Contains"` as Default filter my Secondary Filter.

Answer (score 0):

```
.Filter(x=>x.Add(y=>y.CustomerName).Contains("").And().Contains(""))
```

You can use "And()" for and operations or "Or()" for or operations

Comment: It works only first time
But when we Clear the Filter then again it becomes Default as "Is equal to"

Comment: So you need a JS function which fired when the clear button is clicked , am I right ?

Comment: What kind of JS function? 
then I haveto write JS code for each column which will form a Messy code, Isn't it?

Comment: You right, but JS is the only way to do this, At least I know like that. And I think if filter was cleared, no matter which one is selected contains or isequealto .

Comment: If you insist on doing that http://www.telerik.com/forums/grid-filter-default-operator 
Take a look this site, you can modify databound event as clear button pressed.